# Multiply and Sum results if cells match criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to multiply A:A*B:B whenever C:C = "Open", then sum their results when there's more than one "Open" in column C, and leave the cell blank when there's no "Open" in column C.

Here's the link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BgYcRx6-Ig3AkRNURr2-5Wz3vX5qG4J7SvHt8FlqrHw/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUM`:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(A2:A*B2:B*(C2:C="Open")))
```

or `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A*B2:B*(C2:C="Open"))
```

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to add a condition to the formula? This sum should happen only when Column D (for dates) is >= 2021/01/01 and <= 2021/01/31. That gets more complicated for me. Thanks.

Comment: @iamthe202 use ```=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A*B2:B*(C2:C="Open")*(D2:D>=DATE(2021;1;1))*(D2:D<=DATE(2021;1;31)))```